# Что такое окрестность (N) в локальном поиске?

Tags: алгоритм

Никак не могу понять на примере допустим задачи коммивояжера, что есть в алгоритме локального поиска окрестность (обозначается в виде N)? Можете пример привести разных окрестностей данной задачи?

Comment: Функция окрестности для каждого допустимого решения задает множество соседних решений, в некотором смысле близких к данному

Comment: То есть на примере задачи коммивояжера существует только одна окрестность, в которую входят все города? Поскольку, исходя из определения, из этой окрестности можно будет получить любое решение...

Comment: окрестность определяется функцией, от выбора этой функции зависит эффективность алгоритма. Есть граф решений и у каждого решения этой функцией определяются соседние решения..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример: епсилон-окрестностью точки называется множество точек, удаленных от данной не далее чем на величину епсилон